# perl expression && and eq

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script where I can add a prefilter.

```
if ($row->{'category'}  eq 'Software') { return undef; }
```

this works as expected.

But if I do this

```
if ($row->{'category'}  eq 'Software' &&  $row->{'title'} =~ m/EDU|OLP|Molp|MOLP|Media/) { return undef; }
```

I can't get it to work. I don't get any errors.

I spent the last hour on line looking for a solution but I can't seem to find it.

I have also tried `and` instead of `&&`.

This is the `Data::Dumper` output of `$row`

```
$VAR1 = {
      'manufacturer_model' => 'FQC-02310           ',
      'junk' => '42.03',
      'manufacturer' => 'Microsoft                     ',
      'model' => 'MSWIN81     ',
      'price' => '28.02',
      'title' => 'Win Pro SA EDU NL                       ',
      'category' => 'Software            ',
      'stock' => '251'
    };
```

Comment: Can you show what `Data::Dumper` thinks about `$row`?

Comment: i  have added output from the dumper..

Comment: Clearly, as I said in my comment, the `category` field has multiple spaces after the text. You are populating the structure wrongly. Please show the code that generates this hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$row->{'category'}  eq 'Software'
```

Because $row->{'category'} is actually

```
'Software            '
```

With that in mind, this should work:

```
$row->{'category'} =~ /^Software\s*$/
```

Comment: this worked.looks like the space after the software was the cause. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your hash fields have trailing spaces after the text values. If you are building the hash properly, for instance using `Text::CSV`, then you must process the data you have collected using

```
s/\s+\z// for values %$row
```

before interrogating it. But if the spurious whitespace is a result of incorrect decoding of CSV data then you should fix that instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row->{'category'} = 'Software';
$row->{'title'} = 'Blank Media';
if (
    $row->{'category'}  eq 'Software'
    &&  $row->{'title'} =~ m/EDU|OLP|Molp|MOLP|Media/
) { print "OK!\n"; }
```

That prints "OK!" It looks to me like your data isn't what you expected it to be (you have a problem in `$row->{'title'}`). Check your source data, check your parser.

Comment: this is a sample row."Software            ","MSWIN81     ","Win Pro SA EDU NL                       ","FQC-02310           ","Microsoft                     ",28.02,42.03,251 .. title is 3rd one..

Comment: Then the problem is that there is a space after `Software` and so the category doesn't equal `'Software'`

Comment: @naf That does not help solve the problem, because it is not what is in `$row`, it is what you *think* is in `$row`. Use Data::Dumper and *show* exactly what is in `$row` instead, and/or show the code that puts the input into `$row`.

Answer (score -1):

If you provided sample data of what you'd expect to match and not match, that would help.

*EDIT*
Based on the sample data, I'd change your regex to:

```
$row->{'title'} =~ /(EDU|OLP|Molp|MOLP|Media)/i
```

Comment: I was hoping for sample data from the csv file.  With regards to your regex, try m/(EDU|OLP|Molp|MOLP|Media)/

Comment: here is a sample data .."Software            ","MSWIN81     ","Win Pro SA EDU NL                       ","FQC-02310           ","Microsoft                     ",28.02,42.03,251

Comment: -1 your two changes (adding capture groups and case insensitivity) are clearly irrelevant to the problem.  Capture groups are  bad style unless you explicitly need to capture a part of a match.

Comment: How is case insensitivity irrelevant?  He listed Molp and MOLP.  Ultimately, I should have edited to remove one of the two.  What do you suggest?